# Streaming video from chunked data to endpoint in Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, mediarecorder

I'm trying to create an app where I can send Webcam video from a browser MediaRecorder via Websocket to a node server which will hold the chunked data in memory and serve it via and endpoint handler.

I can receive the data, create a Passthrough stream, and serve the endpoint, but the html5 video player which appears displays nothing. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

client:

```
 serverVideoStreamConnection  = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.hostname + ':8443/');
  serverVideoStreamConnection.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

  if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(recordStream).catch(errorHandler);
  } else {
    alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
  }
}

function recordStream(stream) {

  console.log("Started recording")

  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start(10);

  function handleDataAvailable(event) {
    if (event.data.size > 0) {
      serverVideoStreamConnection.send(event.data);
    } else {
      // ...
      console.log("Data not available")
    }
  }
```

server:

```
let video = new PassThrough();

wss.on('connection', function (ws) {

  ws.on('message', function (message) {
    // Broadcast any received message to all clients


    if (typeof message !== 'string') {
       video.write(new Buffer.from(message));        
    } else {
      wss.broadcast(message);
    }
}

server.get('/video', handleVideo)

function handleVideo(request, response) {
  const header = {
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
  };

  response.writeHead(206, header);
  video.pipe(response);
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with a lot of this stuff in particular, but you'll probably want to give more information about the recipient client. Are they viewing at the same time? What does their client code look like? etc.

Comment: Additionally, this is a nitpick I think, but you should use `Buffer.from(message)`, not `new Buffer.from(message)`. I doubt that's relevant to the problem in particular, though.

Comment: Also (sorry -- not trying to spam), I feel like your edit actually made things less clear. What is `streamToServer`, for example?

Comment: @RiverTam check now, I think it's clearer now

Comment: @RiverTam by recipient client, I assume you mean the client accessing '/video' endpoint. For testing I'm just point my browser at the endpoint, and seeing an unplayable or empty html5 video. The eventual use case is to use the URL as a media source for Open Broadcasting Software application